# Perforce file(s) not on client view

Tags: perforce

i was hoping someone could point me in the right direction? I am trying to set up a second depot, but whenever i try adding files it will spit out this message ' not in client view'.

The primary depot is up and running fine for a unreal project, but i can't figure out how to set up a second one. I made sure to exclude the primary depot tree when creating a new workspace and also made sure to point it to the correct workspace directory.

Comment: I think i firgured it out! If you click on 'edit workspaces' comparing both primary and secondairy workspaces, I noticed how it added the depot name twice, before and after the //.  In the workspace mappings drop down. I deleted the extra part, so it looked simialr to the primary one and bingo! no error and the files was submitted to the depot.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the actual client view as part of the question, but I suspect that the way you've fixed it, you can't submit (or sync) files in the primary depot now...

Answer (score 0):

Your client view defines which depot files are mapped to your workspace, and where they're mapped to.  If your client view looks like:

```
Root: C:\Perforce

View:
    //apples/... //your-client/apples/...
    //pears/... //your-client/pears/...
```

both the `apples` and `pears` depots are mapped to your workspace as follows:

```
//apples -> C:\Perforce\apples
//pears  -> C:\Perforce\pears
```

If you try to add a local file that is not in either of those locations, you will get an error:

```
C:\Perforce>p4 add gravenstein.jpg
gravenstein.jpg - file(s) not in client view.
```

This is because according to your View, *that file doesn't belong in either depot*.  You need to put the file in a location that you've mapped so that Perforce can figure out which depot (and which directory) it goes in.

```
C:\Perforce>move gravenstein.jpg apples
        1 file(s) moved.
C:\Perforce>p4 add apples\gravenstein.jpg
//apples/gravenstein.jpg#1 - opened for add
```

In your comment, you mentioned removing "the extra part".  Suppose you changed your View to look like:

```
Root: C:\Perforce

View:
    //apples/... //your-client/apples/...
    //pears/... //your-client/...
```

Now your client root maps directly to the `pears` depot, and the `apples` depot is no longer mapped anywhere!

```
C:\Perforce>p4 add pippin.jpg
//pears/pippin.jpg#1 - opened for add
C:\Perforce>p4 add apples\honeycrisp.jpg
//pears/apples/honeycrisp.jpg#1 - opened for add
```

This is because later lines always take precedence.  By flipping the order of the View lines you can make it so that *most* of the workspace is mapped to `pears`, but there's an exception for the local `apples` directory:

```
View:
    //pears/... //your-client/...
    //apples/... //your-client/apples/...
```

```
C:\Perforce>p4 add bartlett.jpg
//pears/bartlett.jpg#1 - opened for add
C:\Perforce>p4 add apples\granny_smith.jpg
//apples/granny_smith.jpg#1 - opened for add
```

However, I'd usually recommend that parallel depot paths (e.g. two top-level depots) be represented by two parallel local directories (the default) rather than nesting them inside each other -- it makes it easier to reason about what file goes where if the depot and the workspace mirror each other as much as possible.  Just remember that you need to put local files in the directory that goes with the depot you want to add them to.